# Saving an object (with defaults) in Mongoose/node

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have an object passed to a function, and want to save a DB entry with those values, with the option to have some defaults.

In practical terms...

I have a schema like this in Mongoose:

```
var Log = new Schema({
  workspaceId    : { type: String, index: true },
  workspaceName  : { type: String, index: true },
  loginSession   : { type: String, index: true },
  loginToken     : { type: String, index: true },
  logLevel       : { type: Number, enum:[0,1] },
  errorName      : { type: String, index: true },
  message        : { type: String, index: true },
  reqInfo        : { type: String },
  data           : { type: String },
  loggedOn       : { type: Date, index: true },
});
mongoose.model('Log', Log);
```

To write things on this table, I have something like:

```
exports.Logger = function(logEntry){
  var Log = mongoose.model("Log"),
      req = logEntry.req;

  log = new Log();

  // Sorts out log.reqInfo
  if ( logEntry.req){
    log.reqInfo = JSON.stringify({
      info   : req.info,
      headers: req.headers,
      method : req.method,
      body   :req.body,
      route  :req.route,
      params: req.params    
    });
  } else {
    logEntry.reqInfo = {};
  }

  // Sorts out all of the other fields with sane defaults.
  // FIXME: improve this code, it's grown into something ugly and repetitive
  log.workspaceId = logEntry.workspaceId ? logEntryworkspaceId. : '';
  log.workspaceName = logEntry.workspaceName ? logEntry.workspaceName : '';
  log.loginSession = logEntry.loginSession ? logEntry.loginSession : '';
  log.loginToken = logEntry.loginToken ? logEntry.loginToken : '';
  log.logLevel = logEntry.logLevel ? logEntry.logLevel : 0;
  log.errorName = logEntry.errorName ? logEntry.errorName : '';
  log.message = logEntry.message ? logEntry.message : '';
  log.data = logEntry.data ? logEntry.data : {};

  // Sorts out log.loggedOn
  log.loggedOn = new Date();
  log.save();
}
```

This is absolutely awful code. What's a better way of writing it, without the repetition?

Comment: Asks for mongoose solution, gets mongoose answer, doesn't accept as correct :(

Comment: Asked to improve code, Mongoose was only thereason why I wanted to improve it, if I wanted to know how to do defaults in Mongoose I would have had a different title. I asked about improving this code, not for a way not to have to improve it.

Comment: Your question should have been "How to merge objects in javascript" really...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might be a bit more elegant:

Create a dictionary containing the default values

```
defaults = {
  workspaceName: 'foo',
  loginSession: 'bar',
  loginToken: 'baz'
};

console.log(defaults)
```

Given some values

```
values = {
  workspaceName: 'WNAME1',
  loginSession: 'LS1',
  somethingElse: 'qux'
};

console.log(values)
```

If values doesn't contain an entry for any of the specified defaults, add the default value to values

```
for(i in defaults){
  if(!values[i]){
    values[i] = defaults[i];
  }
}

console.log(values)
```

Comment: I was just hoping Node had something ready to go... but obviously not! Thank you, answer accepted.

Comment: In jQuery there's an extend method that makes merging objects easier. There are a couple of node ports of this (none of which I've used). E.g. https://github.com/dreamerslab/node.extend. Tilman's answer about using defaults in the schema is probably better for a mongoose specific solution.

Comment: Underscore's _.extend() is what I use for this.

Answer (score 10):

I dont understand your code. So, if a value isn't set you want it to be set to empty string `''`?

If you want defaults, easiest way is to just define them in your schema.

```
var Log = new Schema({
  workspaceId    : { type: String, index: true, default: 'your default here' },
  //...
  loggedOn       : { type: Date, index: true, default: Date.now }
});
```

From [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-default)